# Git pull from specific branch with specified URL

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull, pull

I am working on a branch of git. I want to take pull on this branch specifying the URL alongwith it. 
I have tried

```
git pull origin <branch> <url>
```

but it says error "fatal: Invalid refspec "

Both commands when ran independently works fine.

1 ) `git pull origin <branch>` 
  Takes pull from  successfully.

2) `git pull <url>`
  Takes pull from specified URL but from master branch instead.

I want to take pull from  specifying the URL alongwith it so that it doesn't read git's config file and takes pull from 'branch' and 'url'.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do here, but the URL part of the request is baked into what you have labelled as `origin`.  If you want your Git client to point to a different repository, then update `origin`.

Comment: `git pull <url> <branch>`

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay that worked. Is it same for push as well?

Comment: Yes. `origin` is just an alias of the url. When a specific url is used, `origin` or other remotes are not necessary.

Answer (score 9):

You need to provide the command `git pull web_url branch_name`

Answer (score 1):

Add a new remote:

`git remote add alt <URL>:/path/to/repo`

Fetch the content of the repo:

`git remote update`

And pull the changes from the branch you want:

`git pull alt <branch>`

Comment: i had some kind of golden year moment where i *(incorrectly)* recalled the correct syntax for <URL>.  

the url syntax (in a nutshell) *IS* `git@github.com:username/repository.git`  _(NOT_ `username@github.com:repository.git` _)_